Robfig cron retry
If the cron job fails, is there a feature in robfig cron scheduler to retry a certain number of times?
func funcScheduler() {
    c := cron.New()
    
    c.AddFunc("0 12 14 * * *", func(){test()})

    c.start()

}

If the test() returns an error then how to retry again without waiting for the next run according to the cron job schedule and try n number of times as soon as error returned.

We can add a logic under the expectation block to increment the retry count when the error occurs and call the method again but how to override the time "0 12 14 * * *" so that once the job fails then do not want to wait for the next scheduled run.

Job.Run, does not return anything, so any retries need to be handled within the job (i.e. your function).SkipIfStillRunning (or DelayIfStillRunning) may be useful to prevent concurrent instances of the job if that's an issue.

how can we unit-test the cron job in Go?
